# Select options from multi-select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using select_tag from rails with bootstrap multi-select functionality. I am able to show options. But how to select options using jquery on page load.

select tag code 
  `<%= select_tag 'test', options_from_collection_for_select(@test, "id", "name"), :class => "form-control", :multiple => "multiple" %>`

```
$('#test').multiselect({ 
  includeSelectAllOption: true,
  enableFiltering:true         
});
```

When i use

```
 $("#test").val(["some_value_of_option", "some_value_of_option"]).prop("selected", true);
```

The above code is not working to select options.
Thanks in advance for help..

Comment: How is it not working?

Answer (score 1):

Why not do it without jQuery but directly from HTML?

```
<form>
  <select multiple="multiple" id="test" class="multiselect">
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three" selected>Three</option>
    <option value="four"  selected>Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

And if you really need to use jQuery we can extend Madalin's answer of course to update the view:

```
$("#test").find('option[value="cheese"]').prop("selected", true);
$("#test").find('option[value="mozarella"]').prop("selected", true);

// Don't forget to update view
$("#test").multiselect('refresh');
```

Comment: The drop-down values will change based on other drop-down value. There is onchange() on first drop-down. It will be useful if we can select using jquery

Comment: This is correct ! also you can use `select` option to change values like this (in case someone needs) `$('#test').multiselect('select', ['some_value_of_option1','some_value_of_option2']);`

Comment: Thanks for your response i have followed rails way of selecting options. I have selected  from options_from_collection_for_select

Answer (score 1):

we can pass selected values in the form of array as third parameter for  options_from_collection_for_select.

e.g.,
    options_from_collection_for_select(@test, "id", "name", ["1","2","3"])

Comment: Ok, however, you said it was supposed to depend on other already selected values and should be updated when changed. Does this work for that too?

Answer (score 0):

Use `find` and the attribute selector to select the elements with the values

try the following:

```
 $("#test").find('option[value="some_value_of_option", option[value="some_value_of_option"]').prop("selected", true);
```